# Facebook .hidden_elem

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

so im currently trying to find the .hidden_elem class which is used in the facebook 'like box' iFrame, this is so when the .hidden_elem is activated i can show certain content, and when its not there i can hide other content. This is what I have so far

```
$(function() {
    if ($('span').find('.hidden_elem')) {
        alert("NOT LIKED")
    }
    else {
        alert("LIKED")
    }
});
```

At the moment im only getting back 'NOT LIKED', what am i doing wrong?!

S.

Comment: You don't have access to an iframe showing a URL from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

you need a other selector, this elem can have the "hidden_elem" class or not

```
$(function() {
    if ($('span').find('.like_box').hasClass('hidden_elem')) {
        alert("NOT LIKED")
    }
    else {
        alert("LIKED")
    }
});
```

Comment: this will still not work as he has no access to the iframe dom

Comment: to select the content of the iframe dom, you must get the content like: $("iframe").contents(); so : $('.class-conts-of-iframe').contents().find('.like_box').hasClass('hidden_elem'))

Comment: you cannot access the dom of an iframe that is not of the same domain